# Make gnome-screenshot ignore XDG_PICTURES_DIR

Tags: gnome, screenshot, gnome-screenshot

I tried the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-screenshot auto-save-directory "file://$HOME/screenshots
```

And it didn't appear to do anything. `gnome-screenshot` seems to ignore this command and only use `XDG_PICTURES_DIR` to make decisions. I can set `XDG_PICTURES_DIR` to `~/screenshots`, which I did and it works, but I would like to separate screenshots and pictures. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: gnome-screenshot has the `-f` option which allows you to specify a filename and its path. I use `$HOME/wherever/"$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)".png`.

Answer (score 2):

Gnome developer has changed the way the schema behaves,  you may see the bugzilla page regarding the whole ordeal → https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=699642.

However you can install [Screenshot Locations](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1179/screenshot-locations/) extension to achieve exactly what you want, with the extension installed— you can change the default directory to save your screenshot seamlessly.

[Another workaround](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=699642#c40) to this would be disabling the shortcuts in the Keyboard Shortcuts, then add new ones which uses `gnome-screenshot` command. This also works and still respect the `auto-save-directory` schema.